# How to fix a missing Xcursor.h file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vlang

Recently, I was trying to install V on my Ubuntu system. It seemed to have worked, but when I tried to run a game written in V to test that it was successful. I received an error saying that my system couldn't find a file called Xlib.h. I installed xlib, and tried again, this time I received an error in the terminal saying that Xlib2.h is missing. I installed xlib again and tried again to run the file. I received this error:
`builder error: 'X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h' not found`
I searched google for answers on what this could be caused by, and couldn't find an answer, likely because V isn't a very common language. If anyone knows what caused this or more importantly how to fix it, your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Googling seems to mention trying installing libraries such as libxcursor-dev or xorg-dev. Have you tried installing either?

Comment: On-line search → https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=Xcursor.h&searchon=contents ....... and by using apt-file : `sudo apt install apt-file` .............. → `apt-file search Xcursor.h`

Answer (score 5):

I had to install `libxcursor-dev` on my Ubuntu 22.04, so just

```
sudo apt install libxcursor-dev
```